# Add Input to TupleList

Tags: java, list, tuples

I created a new class with for a new List with 2 entries:

```
public class NodeList<T, I> {
        public final T type;
        public final I id;

        public NodeList (T type, I id){
            this.type = type;
            this.id = id;
        }

        public T getT() { return type; }
        public I getI() { return id; }
}
```

Now I want to create this List inside another class (Controller of my javafx BorderPane)

```
List<NodeList> nodeList = new ArrayList<NodeList>();
```

And I want to add two Strings in this List.

```
public void addNodeList(){
    String a = "a";
    String b = "b";
    nodeList.add(a, b);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What problems you are facing? What errors are you getting? Show it to us.

Comment: I already got a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new object of type `NodeList`. A `List` does not have an add method that takes two strings directly. To fix it, do this:

```
public void addNodeList(){
    String a = "a";
    String b = "b";
    nodeList.add(new NodeList<String, String>(a, b));
}
```

Comment: how can I get for like all "a " ?

Comment: Or how can i get just the first? I want to iterate through all. I try `String func = ViewController.nodeList.getT();` but it says `getT()` is undefined for List<NodeList>

Comment: You need to retrieve an element from the list with the `get(int index)` function. To retrieve the first element of the list, do this: `String func = ViewController.nodeList.get(0).getT();`. Also, you need to define the full type of your list like `List<NodeList<String, String>> nodeList = new ArrayList<NodeList<String, String>>();` to retrieve strings from it.

Comment: You're missing something - the declaration of field `nodeList` was incorrect, should be `List<NodeList<String,String>> nodeList = new ArrayList<NodeList<String,String>>();` (plus of course, that the class name `NodeList` for something that is not a list would be incorrect - suggest to call it `Node`)

Comment: Read ny whole comment. I wrote that at the end. I agree about the name though :)

Comment: Just one more question, when I use `Controllername.nodeList.getI()` to get the id as a String, it says that the method is undefined for the type `List<NodeList<String,String>>`, I'll change the name later ;)

Comment: Oh yea I figured it out .. sorry :) I made a loop with i as an integer, it works fine now, thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are no "implicit constructors" in Java. You have to explicitly instantiate a new `NodeList` to hold the two Strings:

```
public void addNodeList(){
    String a = "a";
    String b = "b";
    nodeList.add(new NodeList<>(a, b));
    // Here -----^
}
```

Comment: how can I get for like all "a " ?

Comment: Or how can i get just the first? I want to iterate through all. I try `String func = ViewController.nodeList.getT();` but it says `getT()` is undefined for List<NodeList>